# How can I limit class not to implement all the methods of Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface

Somewhere I have read this question. How can we handle situation like this:

I have an interface, In that I have four methods: `Add`, `Subtract`, `Multiply`, `Divide`.

I have two classes **A** and **B**.

I want **A** and **B** to implement this Interface. But I want situation like this:

- **A** can access only `Add`, `Subtract`.
- **B** can access only `Multiply`, `Divide`.

Please tell me how is this possible in C#?
Or by some trick if this is possible please let me know.

Comment: As it stands this question doesn't make much sense. If you implement an interface you are agreeing to a contract. If you then hide those methods you are breaking the contract. I suspect you might have missed a few key details.

Comment: What exactly do you want? If I type A a = new A(); a.Multiply(); what should happen? Should the code not compile? If so, which of those two lines should prevent it compiling? Should it compile but throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: As many have pointed out here, you shouldn't do that. Maybe you can restate your problem in more general terms (in a new question) and we can help you find a solution, which doesn't involve partial interface implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid implementing all methods of the interface. If you inherit the interface you have to fulfil it.

In some situations some methods of an interface can't have a useful implementation for a specific class. After you have come to the conclusion that you should implement the interface despite this, there are some things that you can do:

- You can implement a method as doing nothing. If the class already does what's expected without it, you can just accept the method call and silently do nothing.
- You can throw a `NotSupportedException`, if some result is expected by calling the method, that the class can't fulfil. Naturally this should only be done if the method is not crucial for how the interface is supposed to be used.

---

Also, you have the choise of implementing interface members implicitly or explicilty. Implicitly is the normal way, where the member is visible both when the type of the reference is the interface and when it's the class.

To implement a member explicitly makes it only visible when the type of the reference is the interface, not when it's the class.

If the `Multiply` method is implemented explicitly in the class `A` (and the interface is named `ICanCalc`):

```
A obja = new A();
ICanCalc infa = new A();

infa.Multiply(); // works fine
obja.Multiply(); // gives a compiler error
```

However, the method is only hidden, you can still use it by simply casting the reference:

```
(ICanCalc)obja.Multiply(); // works fine
```

Answer (score 6):

The point of an interface is to define a contract between two objects. If you are saying that your object only wants to implement some of the contract, then that breaks the meaning of the interface.

Why don't you use multiple interfaces, one for Add/Subtract and another for Multiply/Divide. Your class can implement any or both of these interfaces.

Comment: Having larger interfaces with optional members (and a means of telling which members an instance supports) rather than using fine-grained interfaces can allow a single wrapper class to be used with types that implement many different subsets of the interface functionality.  Using finer-grained interfaces would necessitate creating a different wrapper class for every subset of capabilities.  To be sure, finer-grained interfaces do have some significant advantages, but so too can the use of optional members. For example, if `IEnumerable<T>` had included `bool CountIsKnown` and `int Count {get;}`

Comment: ...then an `IEnumerable<T>` returned from e.g. `Append` could advertise support for `Count` when the appended collections did likewise.  As it is, there's no clean way for a method to wrap an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` without losing any abilities like `Count` which the underlying collection might possess.

Answer (score 3):

A class that implements an interface must implement all of its methods. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/87d83y5b.aspx) says:

> A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.

It seems to me that what you need is two interfaces:

- `IAdditiveOperators` which implements addition and subtraction.
- `IMultiplicativeOperators` which implements multiplication and division.

Implementing classes can then implement one or other or both.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to go about it:

Either split up your methods between two separate interfaces and implement one interface containing Add and Subtract in class A and the other one containing Multiply and Divide in class B. That of course means you have two interfaces instead of one, so decide if this is a problem.

OR

If you insist on having only one interface, you can declare A and B as abstract (which of course means you cannot instantiate them)

If going the abstract route, you need to mark interface methods you don't want to implement as abstract as well.

Comment: Saying "split up the interface" voids the question

Comment: No, it's a perfectly valid answer, just not the one you might want to hear.

Comment: "I want A and B to implement this Interface" - This leaves no room for your answer

Comment: Just because you want to, doesn't always mean you should, oh and BTW this specific use was addressed in first proposition in my answer as well, leaving no room for your remarks.

Comment: @DavidPilkington A downvote seems a bit harsh, but I agree that the answer should be phrased more like: "You can't do what you're actually asking, but one possible alternative is..."

Comment: @Been Aaronson That's actually constructive remark, I've reworded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Split the interface to two interfaces: one with Add and Substract and name IAddSubstract and another one with Multiply and Divide with name IMultiplyDivide. Then you can add another interface (IOperation) which implements IAddSubstract and IMultiplyDivide